# How to hide my menu for non authenticated users?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have authenticated users to log on my system using this code:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, false);
```

I want to hide my system menu for non authenticated users. Something like this:

```
<% if(???) {%>
   <ul id="menu>
      ...
   </ul>
<% } %>
```

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
```

(This is how it's done in the default ASP.NET MVC template)

Answer (score 4):

if (Request.IsAuthenticated)

There's an example of this in the login user control of the basic mvc project.

if you want roles then

if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("myrole"))

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using roles, but I appreciate to know this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use:

```
<% if(this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: User and it's Identity can be null, so better to use `Request.IsAuthenticated`

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
<% if( HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ) %>
```

or

```
<% if( HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsInRole("roleName") ) %>
```

but the other answers look like they'd also work fine.